# Unable to play OGG audio file in Exoplayer from android Expansion file OBB

Tags: android, ogg, exoplayer, apk-expansion-files

I've recently switched my app audio file resources to a Expansion File. problem is that when I read an audio file using APEZProvider the app doesn't  play anything.

See Exoplayer Error:

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
                     com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (MatroskaExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor) could read the stream.
                         at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractorHolder.selectExtractor(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:705)
                         at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:628)
                         at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:295)
                         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
E/MMParserExtractor: FileSource::FILE_SOURCE_DATA_EN
```

My Custom APEZProvider:

```
public class ZipFileContentProvider extends APEZProvider {
String AUTHORITY = "sample.sample";

@Override
public String getAuthority() {
    return AUTHORITY;
}

public Uri readAudioFileFromObb(String filename){

    String path = "content://" + AUTHORITY + File.separator + filename;

    return Uri.parse(path);
}
}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <provider
        android:authorities="sample.sample"
        android:name=".PlaySong.ZipFileContentProvider"
        android:exported="true"
        android:multiprocess="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="mainVersion"
            android:value="14"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

Exoplayer Version = 'r2.2.0'

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to override the `getType()` method as well in `APEZContentProvider` to return the appropriate audio type.

Comment: Hi Nick this is the content of the super class APEZProvider "return vnd.android.cursor.item/asset";  what do I put on that getType() and how do I use it?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not an expert on exoplayer. But the code is open source at https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer - you could look there and see if you can work it out. There is a list of different audio mime types here: https://www.thoughtco.com/audio-file-mime-types-3469485